# Magick++.h: No such file or directory (Even after installing Magick++)

Tags: command-line, compiling, c++, error-handling, imagemagick

I am using a WSL Ubuntu terminal.
I executed the following command to install Magick++:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
```

After this, I checked to make sure that Magick++.h has been installed or not by the following command:

```
sudo apt-file find Magick++.h
```

This showed me the following result:

```
graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat: /usr/include/Magick++.h
libgraphicsmagick++1-dev: /usr/include/GraphicsMagick/Magick++.h
libmagick++-6-headers: /usr/include/ImageMagick-6/Magick++.h
```

Which I assume, means that the Magick++.h header file has been successfully installed for use.

So I try to execute my C++ programme like so:

```
g++ -o main mycppprog.cpp
```

But this throws me the following error:

```
fatal error: Magick++.h: No such file or directory
   11 | #include <Magick++.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I don't understand why this inconsistency is there. Or is there something that I am missing?
Kindly guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which I assume, means that the Magick++.h header file has been successfully installed for use.

This will show you what packages provide the file you searched for and does not show what is installed on your system.

Using the command:

```
apt-file find Magick++.h
```

shows:

```
graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat: /usr/include/Magick++.h
libgraphicsmagick++1-dev: /usr/include/GraphicsMagick/Magick++.h
libmagick++-6-headers: /usr/include/ImageMagick-6/Magick++.h
```

so this tells you that the following packages:

```
graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
libgraphicsmagick++1-dev
libmagick++-6-headers
```

provide the files listed accordingly.

Therefore, run the following commands to install the packages that provide those files:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat libgraphicsmagick++1-dev libmagick++-6-headers
```

Comment: It looks like `libmagick++-6-headers` is a dependency of `libmagick++-dev` so it should already be installed. Most likely, the one that is missing for you is `graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat` as this installs the file directly to the default `/usr/include/` directory. Also, it [shows here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/libmagick++-dev) that `graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat` provides `libmagick++-dev`. In any case, installing all three should satisfy what it's looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the information and the guidance. This helped.